# Зачем нужны функции:

Tags: python

Зачем нужны функции:
Тип ответа: Одиночный выбор • с выбором одного правильного ответа из нескольких предложенных вариантов

- чтобы получить сумму х и у
- чтобы не дублировать участки функции
- чтобы создать цикл

Comment: Думаю, шансов нет.

Comment: А вы попробуйте по очереди каждый ответ подставить и подумать - подходит он или нет. Могут быть функции с другим назначением или нет. Хотя формулировки тут не очень корректные, но догадаться можно.